# Transaction try/catch block - necessary or not?

Tags: t-sql

I have some CRUD operations in SQL procedure that I need to set in transaction.

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  --some statements
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  --return ERROR_MESSAGE() as output parameter or in select, otherwise it will be supressed
END CATCH
```

I call this procedure from service and that call is written inside try block. My question is: Is it better to write this part of procedure without try/catch block since we will catch exception in catch block of service method? Will the transaction be rolled back automatically after exception? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Catch & Rollback will undo any changes within the Database, whereas the Exception handling in the WebService will only catch the error after it happens - it won't touch the data.

You could automatically rollback any failed transactions in SQL, or start the [Transaction in the WebService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx), but simply catching an exception in the WebService can't affect any data unless you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: BEGIN TRANSACTION
  --some statements
  --exception
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
You say that after exception (in line before COMMIT) transaction won't be rolled back automatically, or what?

Comment: It will, sorry. What I meant was if you didn't want the try-catch in SQL for whatever reason you could use something like  [XACT_ABORT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259192(SQL.80).aspx) (SQL Server).  I'd always use the Try/catch though, and I'd guess that's the recommended approach.